# How do you tell Visual Studio to compile an external library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, curl, visual-studio-2013

I've never tried to use external libraries in a C++ project before so this might seem like an obvious question (I'm coming from a C# background)

I want to use libcurl in my project, so I downloaded the source as a zip file [from here](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) and extracted the folder to my "libs" folder which Visual Studio knows to look in. I then included the header file like this: `#include <curl\include\curl\curl.h>`, and I know that works fine because it gives me the right parameter info etc.

This is my main method:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CURL *curl;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    return 0;
}
```

Now the problem is, as soon as I try to compile the project, I get the error `unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_init`. Now this makes sense because I never told Visual Studio to include any cpp files, just a .h file. How do I tell it where to look for the .cpp source files, and how do I know which files to include?

(I do want to compile from the source code because I plan to build the project on linux later on)

Comment: Did you include all the source files into your project?

Comment: That's my question - how do I do that, and how to I know which source files to include

Comment: There are folders in the zip file - winbuild and vs.  Look in there for project files, etc.

Comment: Check the Zip for building instructions; build it per instructions; link against it. Failing that create a static library project, add the .cpp files to it, and hope for the best. If it builds, link against it. You can't just extract the .cpp files into your libs folder (that's where you put your .lib).

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the project setting (in the context menu of the project), then go to the linker settings and check two options: the search path for the libraries and the libraries used.

Comment: That's not what he asked.  He wants to compile the source.